# Как вставить в приложение .swf?

Tags: android, swf

Есть swf файл, хочу его отобразить в приложении, пробовал с WebView, не очень получилось! можно ли другим способом это сделать, может конвертировать в кадры и санимировать или еще как?

Answer (score 1):

Вот [здесь](http://portofollo.blogspot.com/2012/08/apk-android-swf-air.html) пошагово описано как это сделать на примере игры, но смартфон по умолчанию в браузере должен флэш поддерживать, либо он должен быть установлен. Еще [тут](http://blog.snowflax.com/native-imei-action-script-extension-for-android/) предлагают вариант, вроде как ничего от телефона не требуется, но мороки много.

Еще действительно, можно это дело раскадрировать и сделать анимацию, софт не подскажу который делает из свф кучу спрайтов, но он определенно есть. AndEngine - библиотека инкапсулирует OpenGL и как раз заточена на работу со спрайтами и двумерной графикой, сам не пробовал но многие хвалят.

Answer (score 0):

сам webView по  сути и не должен его отображать, попробуй к нему как то плеер прикрутить, не знаю на сколько это реально - не работал с swf файлами